# Using blur event, how do I make sure the blur event goes before the submit button?

Tags: javascript

Assume I write Bob on the input but I still remain focused on the input then I click register. The error wont show because I still remained focused on the input. My question is, how do I make sure the error shows before I click submit with regular javascript?

```js
function check(form) {
  username = document.querySelector(form).querySelector("input[name=username]")
  username.addEventListener('blur', e => {
    if (username.value === "Bob") {
      const label = document.createElement('label')
      label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Your name cant be bob"))
      username.parentNode.insertBefore(label, username.nextSibling)
    }

  })
}
check("#formTest")
```

```html
<h2>Registration</h2>
<form action="" id="formTest" name="registration">

  <label for="firstname">Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" /> <br />

  <button type="submit">Register</button>

</form>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add where you execute `check()`

Comment: De-anonymise the function and call it on submit as well as blur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `keyup` event it is working as expected. Please check the code snippet.

```js
function check(form) {
  username = document.querySelector(form).querySelector("input[name=username]")
  username.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    if (username.value === "Bob") {
      const label = document.createElement('label')
      label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Your name cant be bob"))
      username.parentNode.insertBefore(label, username.nextSibling)
    }
  })
}
check("#formTest")
```

```html
<h2>Registration</h2>
<form action="" id="formTest" name="registration">
  <label for="firstname">Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" /> <br />
  <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

De-anonymise and reuse

Not trivial when using dynamic generated error

```js
let form, username;
const testBob = e => {  e.preventDefault()
  let error = document.getElementById("error");
  if (error) error.style.display="none";
  if (username.value === "Bob") {
    error = document.getElementById("error") || document.createElement('label')
    if (!error.id) {
      error.id="error";
      error.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Your name can't be bob"))
      username.parentNode.insertBefore(error, username.nextSibling)
    }
    if (e.type === "submit") e.preventDefault()
    error.style.display="";
  }
};

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  form = document.querySelector("#formTest")
  username = form.querySelector("input[name=username]")
  username.addEventListener('blur', testBob)
  form.addEventListener('submit', testBob)
});
```

```html
<h2>Registration</h2>
<form action="" id="formTest" name="registration">

  <label for="firstname">Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" /> <br />

  <button type="submit">Register</button>

</form>
```

Comment: This. I would add ``toLowerCase()`` on where it checks if username is equal to bob. But his original code would work too if he used ``keyup``

Comment: If you use the keyup/keydown (I would use "input" event) then the error will appear/blink when typing Bobby too

Answer (score -1):

You're using the wrong event listener in this instance. You'd likely want to use `keyup` rather than `blur`. I also can't see where you are calling on `check();` anywhere in your code.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I referenced `keydown` but after having been able to properly test `keyup` is the value you want.

Comment: Yes, and look at my edit after your edit @jimmyjimmy